# How to query a data-frame to nearest lowest or highest values of column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datatable

```
def table():
    """
    :return:
    """
    df_table = pd.DataFrame()
    df_table['ph'] = [0.5, 0.8, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 5.25, 5.75, 6.25, 6.80]
    df_table[38.0] = [25.37, 22.86, 10.16, 5.08, 2.54, 1.52, 1.02, 0.76, 0.51, 0.25, 0.18, 0.10, 0.08, 0.05]
    df_table[52.0] = [25.37, 25.37, 25.37, 17.78, 7.62, 3.30, 1.78, 1.27, 1.02, 0.76, 0.51, 0.38, 0.25, 0.13]
    df_table[79.0] = [25.37, 25.37, 25.37, 25.37, 10.16, 5.08, 2.54, 2.29, 1.78, 1.27, 0.76, 0.51, 0.38, 0.18]
    df_table[93.0] = [25.37, 25.37, 25.37, 25.37, 14.22, 7.11, 3.56, 3.18, 2.54, 1.78, 1.02, 0.76, 0.51, 0.25]
    return df_table

table = table()
max_temperature = 38.0
ph_value = 0.8
corrosion_table = table[["ph", max_temperature]]
max_ph = min(a for a in corrosion_table['ph'] if a >= ph_value)
corrosion_value = corrosion_table.loc[(corrosion_table["ph"] == max_ph)]
corrosion_rate = float(corrosion_value[max_temperature])
```

How do I query a value of ph_value = 0.85 (ph_value = 0.85) and temperature = 45.0.

Because there is no ph_value of 0.85 it should find ph value of 0.8 which is closest and max(smaller) to given value and similarly, since there is no temperature of 45.0, it should match to closest (less) which is 38.0.

Resulting in the value of 22.86 (max_temperature = 45.0) without interpolating. Value should be able to find closest to the column and row. IF value is passed out of the table such as max_temperature = 100.0 how can I change result to np.nan instead of error.

Thank you for your help, any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```py
ph_min = 0
ph_max = 7
temp_min = 0
temp_max = 100 - 0.01
infinity = 1e9
df_table[temp_max] = np.nan

mid_values_ph = (df_table.ph[1:].values + df_table.ph[:-1].values) / 2
new_index = np.concatenate((np.array([ph_min]), mid_values_ph, np.array([ph_max])))
interval_index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(new_index)

df_table = df_table.set_index(interval_index).drop("ph", axis=1)

temperatures = df_table.columns
mid_value_temperatures = (temperatures[1:] + temperatures[:-1]) / 2
mid_value_temperatures.values[-1] = temp_max
new_columns = np.concatenate((np.array([temp_min]), mid_value_temperatures, np.array([infinity])))
interval_columns = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(new_columns)
df_table.columns = interval_columns

df_table.to_markdown()
```

Outputs:

```
|               |   (0.0, 45.0] |   (45.0, 65.5] |   (65.5, 86.0] |   (86.0, 99.99] |   (99.99, 1000000000.0] |
|:--------------|--------------:|---------------:|---------------:|----------------:|------------------------:|
| (0.0, 0.65]   |         25.37 |          25.37 |          25.37 |           25.37 |                     nan |
| (0.65, 1.025] |         22.86 |          25.37 |          25.37 |           25.37 |                     nan |
| (1.025, 1.5]  |         10.16 |          25.37 |          25.37 |           25.37 |                     nan |
| (1.5, 2.0]    |          5.08 |          17.78 |          25.37 |           25.37 |                     nan |
| (2.0, 2.5]    |          2.54 |           7.62 |          10.16 |           14.22 |                     nan |
| (2.5, 3.0]    |          1.52 |           3.3  |           5.08 |            7.11 |                     nan |
| (3.0, 3.5]    |          1.02 |           1.78 |           2.54 |            3.56 |                     nan |
| (3.5, 4.0]    |          0.76 |           1.27 |           2.29 |            3.18 |                     nan |
| (4.0, 4.5]    |          0.51 |           1.02 |           1.78 |            2.54 |                     nan |
| (4.5, 5.0]    |          0.25 |           0.76 |           1.27 |            1.78 |                     nan |
| (5.0, 5.5]    |          0.18 |           0.51 |           0.76 |            1.02 |                     nan |
| (5.5, 6.0]    |          0.1  |           0.38 |           0.51 |            0.76 |                     nan |
| (6.0, 6.525]  |          0.08 |           0.25 |           0.38 |            0.51 |                     nan |
| (6.525, 7.0]  |          0.05 |           0.13 |           0.18 |            0.25 |                     nan |
```

Which gives you desired functionality:

```
ph = 0.85
temp = [45, 99.99, 100]
df_table.loc[ph, temp]
```

```
(0.0, 45.0]              22.86
(86.0, 99.99]            25.37
(99.99, 1000000000.0]      NaN
Name: (0.65, 1.025], dtype: float64
```

Explanation:

Column `38.0` is changed to `pandas.Interval(0.0, 45.0]` (part of [pandas.IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html#pandas-intervalindex)), because lowest possible temperature is `temp_min = 0` (excluding), and
middle value between `38.0` and `52.0` is `45.0` (including), rest is analogical.

Column `ph` became Index of the `df_table` and it was changed in similar fashion.

Value for `temp_max` is set to 99.99, so value `100` is not included in lookup.

New column `temp_max` was added so it can handle values to big for lookup.